# Assemble string in DataWeave 2.x (efficiently)

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I wanted to write a function in DataWeave (DW 2.0, Mule Runtime 4.3) that could decorate a text message with a banner of * around it, mostly to help call out events in the log.

What I came up with was this, but it feels a little bit Rube Goldberg still. So is there a much more efficient way to write this that I've overlooked?

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
var msg = "WT 3-4"

fun banner(in) =
    do {
        var width = sizeOf(in) + 4
        var standout = 1 to (width) map "*" joinBy ""
        ---
        standout ++ "\n* " ++ in ++ " *\n" ++ standout
    } 
---
//banner ("Hello World")
banner (msg)
```

This gives me:

```
***************
* Hello World *
***************
```

and

```
**********
* WT 3-4 *
**********
```

respectively.

My objections to this are many, but this question is primarily about the construction of the banner strings.

```
var standout = 1 to (sizeOf(in) + 4) map "*" joinBy ""
```

There HAS to be a better way to arithmetically assemble a string than using map() and joinBy() on the width parameter.

Right?

Comment: Did you try functions like `repeat()` and `rightPad()` from the Strings collection? https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-strings . Also String interpolation can help to save some plus simbols https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-types#string_interpolation

Comment: Yes, the lack of interpolations was one of my other complaints about this. I'll refactor for that.

Comment: I always forget to check for new goodies in the ```dw::core::String``` module. And I'm reminded that I need to give version minor number on DW for a while. The ```repeat()``` function comes alive in DW 2.2.x and later. I will apply that and post answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, that is embarrassing. When this idea is refactored for string interpolation and the use of *the right tool,* the answer looks much better.

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain

import repeat from dw::core::Strings
var msg = "Read the Release Notes!"

fun banner(in) =
    do {
        var width = sizeOf(in) + 4
        var standout = repeat("*", width)
        ---
        "$(standout)\n* $(in) *\n$(standout)"       
    }
    
---
banner(msg)
```

The highly apt output then becomes:

```
***************************
* Read the Release Notes! *
***************************
```